# Transfer file of size 300 MB - 1 GB from client to server using java application

Tags: java, ftp, file-transfer

I am trying to develop a desktop based application which will have a browse button. Once a file is selected by "Open File" dialog. The file should be sent to server(target) machine.

I am unsure of how this can be achieved in java. After searching through internet i found out that. This may be achieved in different ways. Some of them

1. Use FTP commands.
2. Socket Programming.
3. Third party library.

I do not want to use option 1 i.e., FTP because of security. Kindly guide on how this can be achieved ?

Comment: You're asking us what solution best meets your requirements but haven't stated any of your requirements.

Comment: Its opinion based question..  You should try the next 2 options

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, but Swing is entirely irrelevant to this.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use FTP, but it does not fit your needs concerning security, you could switch to Secure FTP (sFTP).

A library offering SFTP file transfer for Java is [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/). Example code for an [sFTP transfer](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html) and even for a [secure copy (scp)](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpTo.java.html) is available on the JSch webpage.